# BLE connection with an iDevice for long hours

Tags: ios, embedded, sensors, btle

I have a sensor board with a nrf51 radio that can connect with an iDevice (using the CoreBluetooth.framework).

The experiment that I'm doing (collecting sensor data overnight) could take advantage of pushing this stream of data over to phone and have the phone store it to a file due to the limited flash size that I have on the sensor board. Although, I wonder if it's possible to maintain a reliable constant BLE connection between the radio and the iDevice overnight (~6-8 hours), provided that both have sufficient power? It wouldn't cut if I lose data due to interruption such as the app being terminated by iOS or BTLE disconnection due to other reasons.

Also, let me know if this question is in the right area of StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running several tests overnight, and the BTLE seems to maintain for more than 24 hours. So I'd say it's very possible to maintain long connections.